# Executing an update query takes a long time

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am executing an update query with 16000 rows of data. It takes a long time. Can anyone suggest a way to reduce the time? Thanks in advance.

```
UPDATE PC 
SET PC.SET_OF_BOOKS = TEMP.SET_OF_BOOKS
FROM dbo.CUSTOMER PC 
INNER JOIN [DM].[CUSTOMER] TEMP ON PC.CUST_NO = TEMP.CUST_NO
```

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: Also, please share the **table structure**, and any indexes you might already have on your table `PC`

Comment: sql-server and no indexes already in the table.

Comment: please share execution plan. It will help

Comment: "no indexes already in the table" - thats your problem then. Add an index as Gordon suggested

Comment: thanks all added index it work find .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this query:

```
UPDATE PC
    SET PC.SET_OF_BOOKS = TEMP.SET_OF_BOOKS
    FROM dbo.CUSTOMER PC INNER JOIN
         [DM].[CUSTOMER] TEMP
         ON PC.CUST_NO = TEMP.CUST_NO;
```

You want an index on `dm.customer(cust_no, set_of_books)`:

```
create index idx_customer on dm.customer(cust_no, set_of_books);
```

This will make the `join` faster.

There might be other issues with the query that you might also want to verify:

- Is `CUST_NO` the same type in both tables?
- Are there multiple rows in `dm.customer` with the the same `CUST_NO`?
- Are most of the rows in `dbo.CUSTOMER` being updated?

These (and no doubt other issues) would suggest other strategies.

Comment: i did not get, can you please explain bit more